# Why does 'docker run -t' redirect stderr to stdout?

Tags: docker, stderr, tty

From `docker run --help`:

```
  -t, --tty                            Allocate a pseudo-TTY
```

Very nice. I use that to get color output automatically. The problem is, it also redirects stderr to stdout.

Without `-t`, stderr isn't redirected, which is what I want:

```
$ docker run ubuntu ls /aaaaaa
ls: cannot access '/aaaaaa': No such file or directory

$ docker run ubuntu ls /aaaaaa 2> /dev/null
```

With `-t`, the error messages are redirected to stdout:

```
$ docker run -t ubuntu ls /aaaaaa
ls: cannot access '/aaaaaa': No such file or directory

$ docker run -t ubuntu ls /aaaaaa 2> /dev/null
ls: cannot access '/aaaaaa': No such file or directory

$ docker run -t ubuntu ls /aaaaaa > /dev/null
```

Why is that? Is there a way to still allocate a pseudo-TTY and keep stderr separate?

e.g. I want to run something like this in CI:

```
docker run ... my-command > out.json
```

while the logger shows warnings and error messages in color.

Comment: Not sure about the original question, but maybe `--env TERM xterm` (/`xterm-256color`) or something could be a way to convince what you’re using to produce color by default without needing the pty?

Comment: `docker run --rm --env TERM=xterm-256color busybox ls /` did not convince `ls` :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your command a shell session so your container can have its own output redirection and not rely on what docker runtime has setup.

This will print error message as usual:

`docker run -t --rm busybox sh -c "ls /aaa"`

This will not print error message to your allocated tty:

`docker run -t --rm busybox sh -c "ls /aaa 2>/dev/null"`

This will print the directory listing of /etc:

`docker run -t --rm busybox sh -c "ls /etc 2>/dev/null"`

Comment: Thank you. I see how this works as a workaround for some situations, but not if I want to capture stdout and stderr, separately, and outside of the container. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Your new edit `logger shows warnings and error messages in color` is totally out of the original context.